# AWS Blue/Green deployment for ECS fails at traffic redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy a `Python3` application using `CodeDeploy` in AWS ECS.
The thing here is that despite the Code Deploy creates the instance, and ECS deploys a task there, the traffic redirection doesn't work.

[image]

I have the following ecs service definition:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
  name                               = "service"
  cluster                            = aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.name
  task_definition                    = aws_ecs_task_definition.task_definition.arn
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 0
  deployment_maximum_percent         = 100
  scheduling_strategy                = "DAEMON"

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = var.target_group_arn[0]
    container_name   = var.namespace
    container_port   = 8080
  }

  launch_type = "EC2"

  depends_on = [aws_ecs_task_definition.task_definition]
}
```

The deployment group is

```
resource "aws_codedeploy_deployment_group" "group" {
  app_name              = aws_codedeploy_app.app.name
  deployment_group_name = aws_codedeploy_app.app.name
  service_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.codedeploy.arn
  autoscaling_groups     = ["my-autoscaling-group"]
  deployment_config_name = "CodeDeployDefault.ECSAllAtOnce"

  ec2_tag_set {
      ec2_tag_filter {
         key   = "deploy"
         type  = "KEY_AND_VALUE"
         value = "tf"
      }
    }

  deployment_style {
    deployment_option = "WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL"
    deployment_type   = "BLUE_GREEN"
  }

   auto_rollback_configuration {
          enabled = true
          events  = ["DEPLOYMENT_FAILURE"]
  }

  load_balancer_info {
    target_group_info {
      name = "my-balancer"
    }
  }

  blue_green_deployment_config {
    deployment_ready_option {
      action_on_timeout    = "CONTINUE_DEPLOYMENT"
    }

    green_fleet_provisioning_option {
      action = "COPY_AUTO_SCALING_GROUP"
    }

    terminate_blue_instances_on_deployment_success {
      action = "TERMINATE"
      termination_wait_time_in_minutes = 0
    }
  }
}
```

Task definition

```
[
    {
      "name": "name",
      "image": "my-image",
      "cpu": 7,
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "logConfiguration": null,
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8081,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 8080
        },
        {
          "hostPort": 8793,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 8793
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "environment": [],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "readOnly": null,
          "containerPath": "/usr/local/airflow/dags",
          "sourceVolume": "dags"
        },
        {
         "readOnly": null,
         "containerPath": "/usr/local/airflow/logs",
         "sourceVolume": "logs"
        },
        {
         "readOnly": null,
         "containerPath": "/helper",
         "sourceVolume": "helper"
        },
      ],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memoryReservation": 128,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null
    }
  ]
```

Comment: What about `appspec.yaml`? How does it look like?

Comment: @Marcin I guess you mean the task definition json file. I just added it

Comment: I mean [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-example.html#appspec-file-example-ecs) file.

Comment: @Marcin not created, at least not in terraform. How does terraform create it?

Comment: I don't know if terraform creates it. You can go to CodeDeploy deployments end check what was used.

Comment: Your deployment group is very confusing. You write its for ecs, but then you have `CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce` which is for EC2. For ecs the deployment configuration is called `CodeDeployDefault.ECSAllAtOnce`. Are you sure your CD application is set to ECS?

Comment: @Marcin sorry, it0s true, it was setup to server. Now is setup to ECS and CodeDeployDefault.ECSAllAtOnce. Despite that it launches the next error:

Error updating CodeDeploy deployment group: DeploymentGroupDoesNotExistException: No Deployment Group found for name:

Comment: Now it makes more sense. You need totally new deployment group along with appsec.yaml file. CodeDepoy for ECS is vastly different from EC2 deployments.